# upload file to a server using lua

Tags: php, lua

I have been trying to upload a file to a webserver using LUA.

My problem is that I want to upload a file using LUA to webserver which mimics uploading a file like from a browser.

I was successfully able to upload file using server, where I can do `file_get_contents('php://input')`, where i get contents and mime_decode on it and save that file.

But, i want to achieve where i can do like `$_FILES['file_name']`, on server side using lua.

so does anybody have idea how to do this in LUA?

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the HTTP sockets library for sending HTTP requests and ltn12 library for filters (file input). Both should be provided with Lua.

```
http = require("socket.http")
ltn12 = require("ltn12")

http.request{
    url = "url://to.server/upload/script.php",
    method = "POST",
    headers = {
        ["Content-Type"] =  "multipart/form-data",
        ["Content-Length"] = sizeOfFile
    },
    source = ltn12.source.file(io.open(pathToLocalFile)),
    sink = ltn12.sink.table(response_body)
}
print(response_body[1]) --response to request
```